# Show that $9a²-4 ab + 6b²> 0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I think we should use square completion, but I can not.

Such inequality is to prove that the quadratic form of a matrix is positive.

Thanks.

Comment: brute force: critical points, check if hessian positive definite, plug in minimum, check if value positive.

Comment: if a= b=0 it's zero so you need more conditions.

Comment: if you multiply throughout by $9$ you can complete that

Comment: When you say that you "can not" use square completion, do you mean that you are unable to, or you are not permitted to?

Comment: @BrianTung I'm unable to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$(2a-b)^2 = 4a^2 +b^2 -4ab$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this can help me. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @LetíciaDal'Canton Well, try to think what you need to add to the right side to get your expression...

Comment: Oh, yes. I could now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In a spirit similar to thanasissdr's answer, consider the function $$f(a)=9a^2-4b \,a+6b^2$$ Its derivative $$f'(a)=18a-4b$$ cancels for $a=\frac {2b}9$ and $$f\left(\frac{2 b}{9}\right)=\frac{50 b^2}{9} $$ which is strictly positive if $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like
part of
$(3a-?b)^2
=9a^2-6?ab+?^2b^2$.
To get
$9a^2-4ab$,
we must have
$6? = 4$
or
$? = \frac23$.
This gives
$(3a-2b/3)^2
=9a^2-4ab+4b^2/9
$.

Therefore

$\begin{align}
9a^2-4ab+6b^2
&=9a^2-4ab+4b^2/9-4b^2/9+6b^2\\
&=(3a-2b/3)^2+(6-4/9)b^2\\
&=(3a-2b/3)^2+(50/9)b^2\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{align}
$

Note that
$9a^2-4ab+cb^2
\ge 0
$ for any
$c \ge 4/9$.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to prove it (which is a pretty standard technique). Assume that we fix a value for $b\neq 0$ and we have the polynomial:
$$f(a) = 9a^2 - (4b)\cdot a + (6b^2).$$

If we calculate the discriminant, we have:
$$D = 16b^2 - 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 6b^2 = -200b^2 \color{red}{\lt 0}.$$ Thus, $f$ has always positive sign for each $a \in \mathbb R$, i.e. $$f(a) >0 \tag 1.$$  But $b$ was chosen randomly, so $(1)$ holds for every $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Basically, the inequality holds when $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$.